# Convert strategy Pine script from v2 to v4 , did it, but got different and wrong results

Tags: pine-script

My original script is based on HeikinAshi strategy with certain conditions.

```
//@version=2
//Heikin Ashi Strategy  V2 by breizh29

strategy("Heikin Ashi Strategy  V2",shorttitle="HAS V2",overlay=true,default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100,initial_capital=100,currency=currency.GBP)
res = input(title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="60")
hshift = input(1,title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame Shift")
res1 = input(title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="180")
mhshift = input(0,title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame Shift")
fama = input(1,"Heikin Ashi EMA Period")
test = input(1,"Heikin Ashi EMA Shift")
sloma = input(30,"Slow EMA Period")
slomas = input(1,"Slow EMA Shift")
macdf = input(false,title="With MACD filter")
res2 = input(title="MACD Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="15")
macds = input(1,title="MACD Shift")




//Heikin Ashi Open/Close Price
ha_t = heikinashi(tickerid)
ha_open = security(ha_t, res, open[hshift])
ha_close = security(ha_t, res, close[hshift])
mha_close = security(ha_t, res1, close[mhshift])

//macd
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
macdl = security(ha_t,res2,macdLine[macds])
macdsl= security(ha_t,res2,signalLine[macds])

//Moving Average
fma = ema(mha_close[test],fama)
sma = ema(ha_close[slomas],sloma)
plot(fma,title="MA",color=lime,linewidth=2,style=line)
plot(sma,title="SMA",color=red,linewidth=2,style=line)


//Strategy
golong =  crossover(fma,sma) and (macdl > macdsl or macdf == false )
goshort =   crossunder(fma,sma) and (macdl < macdsl or macdf == false )

strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long,when = golong)
if (goshort)
    strategy.close("Buy")
```

and my compiled script to v4 is

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Stopperbg

//@version=4

strategy("HAS V3",shorttitle="HAS V3",overlay=true,default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100,initial_capital=1000,currency=currency.USD)
res = input(title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame", type=input.resolution, defval="60")
hshift = input(1,title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame Shift")
res1 = input(title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame", type=input.resolution, defval="180")
mhshift = input(0,title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame Shift")
fama = input(1,"Heikin Ashi EMA Period")
test = input(1,"Heikin Ashi EMA Shift")
sloma = input(30,"Slow EMA Period")
slomas = input(1,"Slow EMA Shift")
macdf = input(false,title="With MACD filter")
res2 = input(title="MACD Time Frame", type=input.resolution, defval="15")
macds = input(1,title="MACD Shift")




//Heikin Ashi Open/Close Price
t = tickerid(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session.regular)
ha_t = heikinashi(t)
ha_open = security(ha_t, res, open[hshift])
ha_close = security(ha_t, res, close[hshift])
mha_close = security(ha_t, res1, close[mhshift])

//macd
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
macdl = security(ha_t,res2,macdLine[macds])
macdsl= security(ha_t,res2,signalLine[macds])

//Moving Average
fma = ema(mha_close[test],fama)
sma = ema(ha_close[slomas],sloma)
plot(fma,title="MA",color=color.lime,linewidth=2,style=plot.style_line)
plot(sma,title="SMA",color=color.red,linewidth=2,style=plot.style_line)


//Strategy
golong =  crossover(fma,sma) and (macdl > macdsl or macdf == false )
goshort =   crossunder(fma,sma) and (macdl < macdsl or macdf == false )

strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long,when = golong)
if (goshort)
    strategy.close("Buy")
```

I followed tutorials and my script is without errors. 
I do this conversion, because I want to add `alertcondition` to get alarm when condition is met.

On v2 there is no alert with added buy or sell signal, Please note that in Pine v4 an `alertcondition` call generates an additional plot. All such calls are taken into account when we calculate the number of the output series per script.
But I got different results. whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That script is misleading and producing unrealistic results.**

Using the default settings, the code is cheating by using future data to calculate the `fma` variable used to trigger Buy/Sell orders. If `hshift == 0` or `mhshift == 0` (the default), then your script will be using future data, and so misleading traders or you.

To avoid this, you should change these lines:

```
hshift = input(1,title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame Shift")
mhshift = input(0,title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame Shift")
```

to:

```
hshift = input(1,title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame Shift", minval = 1)
mhshift = input(1,title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame Shift", minval = 1)
```

See [How to avoid repainting when using security() - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/) for more details.

> Note that the scripts using the source code you reused have been moderated a while back for the exact reason that they were misleading.

Answer (score 0):

so i manage to fix it. 
added  lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on

```
ha_open = security(ha_t, res, open[hshift], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
ha_close = security(ha_t, res, close[hshift], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
mha_close = security(ha_t, res1, close[mhshift], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

they changed lookahead to off by default